# What are pros and cons of using special characters in SQL identifiers?

Tags: sql, special-characters

Should I avoid special characters like "é á ç" in SQL table names and column names?

What are the pros and cons of using special characters?

Comment: You mean in table names? Yes, stick to ASCII. And keep it case-insensitive.

Comment: Or in data? There you can put whatever characters you want, of course. Make sure you configure the database and clients for Unicode support.

Comment: @Thilo Thanks for the help (it was in table names).

Comment: Voting to close as opinion-based since you _can_ use special characters, while the OP is asking if you _should_.  A better question might be to ask for pros and cons of each.

Comment: @DStanley I wish people would make constructive suggestions for *improving* questions, instead of just voting to closing everything.

Answer (score 1):

As you can guess, there are pros and cons. This is more or less a subjective question.

SQL (unlike most programming languages) *allows* you to use special characters, whitespace, punctuation, or reserved words in your table or column identifiers.

It's pretty nice that people have the choice to use appropriate characters for their native language.

Especially in cases where a word changes its meaning significantly when spelled with the closest ASCII characters: e.g. `año` vs. `ano`.

But the downside is that if you do this, you have to use "delimited identifiers" every time you reference the table with special characters. In standard SQL, delimited identifiers use double-quotes.

```
SELECT * FROM "SELECT"
```

This is actually okay! If you want to use an SQL reserved word as a table name, you can do it. But it might cause some confusion for some readers of the code.

Likewise if you use special non-ASCII characters, it might make it hard for English-speaking programmers to maintain the code, because they are not familiar with the key sequence to type those special characters. Or they might forget that they have to delimit the table names.

```
SELECT * FROM "año"
```

Then there's non-standard delimited identifiers. Microsoft uses square-brackets by default:

```
SELECT * FROM [año]
```

And MySQL uses back-ticks by default:

```
SELECT * FROM `año`
```

Though both can use the standard double-quotes as identifier delimiters if you enable certain options, you can't always rely on that, and if the option gets disabled, your code will stop working. So users of Microsoft and MySQL are kind of stuck using the non-standard delimiters, unfortunately.

Maintaining the code is simpler in some ways if you can stick with ASCII characters. But there are legitimate reasons to want to use special characters too.